# Using REGEX inside an IF function

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I am trying to validate zip codes using an if function with a regex.  Can this be done?  I currently just have the if function making sure the zip code is 5 numbers.

below is the regex i want to use

```
(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)
```

Can someone show me where and how i would add this to the if function below?

```
var value = $(this).val();
if( value.length<5 || value==$(this).attr('id') ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');


            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }
```

Comment: to what element you want to test against

Comment: @DevZer0: Thought the same thing but there are other letters missing, `F,I,O,Q,U,W,Z`

Comment: @elclanrs confusing to answer this because he didn't specify which element to test it against with

Comment: it is being tested against an input value that is supposed to be a zip code.  As of now the only verification is that the zip code has to be 5 numbers as you can see above

Comment: added the var value if that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
var ZipCode = "(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)";

if (ZipCode.test(98800)) {
          // true 
 } else {
          // false
 }
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var filter = "(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)";     
if (!filter.test($(this).attr('id').value)) {
    $(this).addClass('error');
    error++;
}
else
{
    $(this).addClass('valid');
}
```

Comment: Strings don't have a `test` method